# Gerrit Code Review - Retrieve file content from Change Edit

Tags: gerrit

Has anyone successfully constructed the correct url to retrieve the file content from this endpoint?

All my attempts have resulted in a status 404.

The documentation is confusing in this link

https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#get-edit-file

Below is the example it provides

```
GET /changes/{change-id}/edit/path%2fto%2ffile
```

this is data from gerrit.

```
{
    "branch": "BR16516",
    "change_id": "Ieb84eb99147fc39d3e117fe61eef8389d2f64611",
    "change_number": "52490",
    "change_revision": "2",
    "file_name": "sql/BR16516-update-order-15102.sql",
    "lines_inserted": 77,
    "size_delta": 2041,
    "status": "A"
}
```

I can't seem to provide a value for {change-id} and {'path%2fto%2ffile'} that gerrit recognises

The value I provided (see shown above) is the same value retrieved from /changes endpoint documented here
- https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#list-changes

This is the code example provided:

Retrieves content of a file from a change edit.

Request
  GET /changes/myProject~master~I8473b95934b5732ac55d26311a706c9c2bde9940/edit/foo HTTP/1.0

In this example, the filename is 'foo' however the {change-id} introduces myProject~master~ and I tried substituting this for the relevant values for my project but with no luck.

If there are other endpoints that will give me plain text from the file in the branch, that will be good too.

Comment: To those who are still struggling to find the way to give folder path in the URL separate the folder with "%2f"

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the file content from this end point

GET /changes/{change-id}/revisions/{revision-id}/files/{file-id}/content

change_id is the id from the change record
revision-id is the revision id from the change record

the change record is from the query changes end point

https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#list-changes

Comment: Is there any API to get the files with content changed in the current patchset which is under review